# Using MySQL to find out an average value

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables

One table called employee which has the following fields: Id, fname,lname 
Another table called Salary which has the follwing fields: Id, salary. 
The tables have values inside

What i am trying to do is to display the average salary of employees with surname of 'smith'.

I have this query:

```
SELECT AVG(Salary) FROM Salary 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE lname = 'smith'
```

But i dont think it will work.

Comment: Do an sql join http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp and then average

Comment: Follow this link. Hope it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859495/using-avg-function-between-two-tables

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
SELECT lname, AVG(Salary) 
FROM Salary 
JOIN employee ON Salary.Id = employee.Id 
WHERE lname= 'smith' 
GROUP BY employee.lname;
```

I've added the group by in case you want to remove the where clause.

Comment: The field might be called `lname` rather than `surname`. It's not really clear from your question, because you use both.

Comment: What does the GROUP BY function do ?

Comment: Sorry its lname -@Chris Lear

Comment: `GROUP BY` tells mysql how to choose which rows to apply the `AVG` command to. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html might be handy

Comment: If you remove the `GROUP BY`, you will see the mean salary for all surnames (I've updated the query to display `lname`.

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to the answer could be written by omitting both the UNION and JOIN operation. TABLE ALIASES have been used to increase readability and to shorten the SQL statement.

```
SELECT e.Lname,avg(s.Salary)
FROM Employee e,Salary s
WHERE e.Id=s.Id
AND e.lname='Smith'
GROUP BY e.Lname;
```

You can read more about aliases in the following links:
http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp